# How to use .islower() for an if statement without modifying the original string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got a variable x that contains the string "Hello". Im checking with .islower() if its lowercase or not and im trying use the output of .islower (true or false) to make the string all lower case in the case it is not.

The problem is: Originally x contains the string "Hello" but after checking it with .islower() that Hello is getting lost and x now contains "True" or "False". I don't want the original content of x to get lost.

Print(x) prints False instead of "hello"

```
x = "Hello".islower()
print(f'x is {x}')
if x == False:
        #return x.lower()
    print("its not all lower case")
    print(x)
```

I thought about this Solution:

I have Variable x containing the string "Hello".
I copy the content of variable X into variable Y.
Variable x will retain the original data (string) and variable y will be only used to check if it is lower case or not and using a if statement that will then print y in lower case in case it is not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

x = "Hello"
x = y
y.islower()
print(f'x is {x}')
if y == False:
    print("¨its not all lower case")
    print(x).lower()
else:
    print(x)
```

Problems are this is not working:

```
x = y
```

I tried to test it and y does not print "Hello"

```
x = "Hello"
y = x
print(y)

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

also I doubt that this is working:

```
y.islower()
```

I have the Impression you can only use .islower()

What would be the clean and right way to do it?

Comment: Store the *string* in `x`, then call `islower()` on `x`. You only stored the boolean result of the `islower()` test.

Comment: Strings are otherwise *immutable*, and `islower()` does't need to mutate anything.

Comment: And `x = y` doesn't assign a new name `y`, it would replace `x`

Comment: `y` has to be in the left part of an assignment before being used

Comment: `print(x).lower()` isn't doing what you think. You probably meant to write: `print(x.lower())`

Comment: x = "Hello".islower()
print(x) will output False so the content of x is now "False"

Comment: ok, so y = x worked, also print(x.lower()) instead of print(x).lower(). Also y=(x.islower()) seems to be the solution

Comment: Why check? If you want a lower case string, then it's not going to be that expensive to simply create one regardless of whether it is already lowercase or not. `x = x.lower()` and done.

Comment: Im thinking long term. I would like to know if it is or not for text processing I would like to do later on when im better in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to convert the string to lowercase, just use `.lower()` unconditionally.

If you want to do something else depending on whether the string is lowercase, try this:

```
if x.islower():
    print("lowercase")
else:
    print("uppercase")
    x = x.lower()
```

Comment: I only want to .lower() if it isn't lower case, thats the whole point.

Comment: @Barry Is the goal to convert the string to lowercase or to also do something else if the string was lowercase?

Comment: yes I want to do other stuff as well at a later stage.

Comment: I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issues Solved, Thanks for everyone that answered it was a big help:

1. x = y is not working, as  Martijn Pieters pointed out.
   but instead of doing that one can simply do this: `y=(x.islower())` since we only want y to contain the answer to the question if x is lower case or not
2. Ive seen examples written like that `print(x).lower()` but it does not seem to be working. `print(x.lower())` Is the answer to that

This code is working so no matter if it will be printed in lower case. It will detect if its not and correct it or simply print it out if it is written in all lower case.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    x = "Hello"
    y=(x.islower())
    print(f"x is {x}")
    if y == False:
        print("its not all lower case")
        print(x.lower())
    else:
        print(x)
```

Here is another example of the solved code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

x = input("Please enter a word:  ")
y=(x.islower())
print(f"Your word is {x}")
if y == False:
    print("Your word is not all in lower case, lett me correct it for you")
    print(x.lower())
else:
     print(x)
```

This is also an option. Thx Solomon:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

x = input("Please enter a word:  ")
print(f"Your word is {x}")
if x.islower():
    print("x is all low")
else:
    print("Your word is not all in lower case, lett me correct it for you")
    print(x.lower())
    x = x.lower()
```